# Interpreting Elastic Net Coefficients and Accuracy Testing

Tags: r, interpretation, accuracy, elastic-net

I have a code for an elastic net model which is predicting the best lambda to use. With this, it provides coefficients for those values. I wanted to see how accurate those coefficients are that it generated, but I'm not sure how to compute accuracy for them. Any thoughts?

Here's the code for the elastic net and dataset:

```
set.seed(12)
n <- 200
coefs <- rep(c(2, -1, 0), each=30)
epsilon <- rnorm(n, 0, 10)
x <- matrix(nrow=n, ncol=90)
for(i in 1:90){
  x[, i] <- rnorm(200, 0, 1)
}
y <- rep(NA, n)
for(i in 1:n){
  y[i] = sum(x[i,]*coefs) + epsilon[i]
}
data <- data.frame(x=x,y=y)

set.seed(12)
dim(data)
head(data)
numericvars <- c(1:90)
sample <- data[1:100,]     #I only wanted the first 100 data observations for this.
x <- as.matrix(sample[,numericvars])
y <- sample$y
newdata <- data.frame(x=x,y=y)

lambdalevels <- 10^seq(7,-2,length=100)

library(glmnet)
ridge.mod=glmnet(x,y,alpha=0,lambda=lambdalevels)
coef(ridge.mod)[,100]
plot(ridge.mod,xvar="lambda")

middle.mod=glmnet(x,y,alpha=0.5,lambda=lambdalevels)
plot(middle.mod,xvar="lambda")

lasso.mod=glmnet(x,y,alpha=1,lambda=lambdalevels)
plot(lasso.mod,xvar="lambda")

set.seed(12)
cv.lasso.mod=cv.glmnet(x,y,alpha=1,lambda=lambdalevels)
plot(cv.lasso.mod)

bestlambda <- cv.lasso.mod$lambda.min
coefs <- predict(lasso.mod, type="coefficients",s=bestlambda)
```

Here are the coefficients I get:

```
91 x 1 sparse Matrix of class "dgCMatrix"

(Intercept) -0.167564375    
x.1          1.631117431
x.2          .          
x.3          .          
x.4          .          
x.5          0.681934674
x.6          0.309141489
x.7          1.099379025
x.8          1.087376314
x.9          0.302149946
x.10         0.015998582
x.11         0.288141307
x.12         1.256299269
x.13         1.056323266
x.14         1.535587611
x.15         1.137616700
x.16         0.225478965
x.17         0.505928229
x.18         .          
x.19         1.190590924
x.20         2.058489311
x.21         .          
x.22         1.688636268
x.23         2.061530905
x.24         0.618335400
x.25         .          
x.26         .          
x.27         0.463405536
x.28         0.028798839
x.29         .          
x.30         1.085691534
x.31        -0.665697847
x.32        -1.452097498
x.33         .          
x.34         .          
x.35         .          
x.36         .          
x.37         .          
x.38         .          
x.39         .          
x.40        -0.009110380
x.41         .          
x.42         0.199324433
x.43         0.694738515
x.44         .          
x.45        -1.496049876
x.46         .          
x.47         .          
x.48        -2.691493897
x.49         .          
x.50        -2.107344734
x.51         0.573354698
x.52        -0.098378699
x.53        -0.003158034
x.54        -1.055646010
x.55        -0.648864691
x.56        -0.185288075
x.57         .          
x.58        -0.003201519
x.59         .          
x.60        -0.330444362
x.61         .          
x.62         .          
x.63         .          
x.64         .          
x.65         .          
x.66         .          
x.67         0.010839710
x.68         .          
x.69         .          
x.70         .          
x.71        -1.512228491
x.72         .          
x.73         0.281044294
x.74         .          
x.75         .          
x.76         .          
x.77        -0.086147448
x.78         .          
x.79         .          
x.80        -0.126396868
x.81         .          
x.82        -1.470280928
x.83         .          
x.84         .          
x.85         .          
x.86         0.005316165
x.87         0.492648763
x.88        -0.730390919
x.89         .          
x.90         0.672031175
```

Any suggestions and thoughts and help will be appreciated!

Thanks!